# request.getParameterNames() is empty after setting the form's enctype to "multipart/form-data"

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

Im developing a simple file upload using JSP, everything works fine until I set the form's enctype to "multipart/form-data", `request.getParameterNames()` is returning empty. Any idea?

Here's my code:

upload.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="login.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="File Name"></input>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"></input>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></input>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
            Enumeration params = request.getParameterNames();
            boolean empty = true;
            while(params.hasMoreElements()){
                String param = params.nextElement().toString();
                out.println(param);
                empty = true;
            }
            if(empty) out.println("No parameters received!");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you happen to use JSF anyway in this case?

Comment: Another food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/

Answer (score 1):

please see here:
[Convenient way to parse incoming multipart/form-data parameters in a Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337056/convenient-way-to-parse-incoming-multipart-form-data-parameters-in-a-servlet)

multipart is parsed differently on the servlet side.
On servlet spec 3 you need to call 'getParts()', on older specs you might want to consider a 3rd party such as Apache FileUpload .

Comment: If you found a duplicate answer, why don't you just flag/vote for close as duplicate?

Comment: Frankly, I wasn't aware of this option. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because of `enctype="multipart/form-data"` so alternatively you can use `@MultipartConfig` annotation (available after `javaee6` and `servlet 3.0`) or `commans-fileupload` as suggested in the below posts:

[request.getParameter on a submit button giving null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992282/request-getparameter-on-a-submit-button-giving-null-value)

[Get parameter when multipart request in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321164/get-parameter-when-multipart-request-in-jsp)

Comment: Im using JSP, I dont have a servlet. Where do you insert @MultipartConfig in JSP?

Comment: What kind of project do you have, if you don't have a Servlet?

Comment: You can also use MultipartFormDataRequest which will be more easy and one more thing its good to use servlet for business logic.

Comment: If you found a duplicate answer, why don't you just flag/vote for close as duplicate?

Comment: because i don't have that much reputation like you ...